# Showing an uncountable union of elements in a $\sigma$-algebra set is in the set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Let {$A_t, t \geq 0, t\in\mathbb{R}$} be a family of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $A_s \subseteq A_t$ for all $0 \leq s\leq t$.

I want to show that $\bigcup\limits_{t \geq 0} A_t \in \mathcal{F}$.

Am I allowed to index the reals with the naturals in this situation such that
$\bigcup\limits_{t \geq 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t = \bigcup\limits^\infty_{i = 1, i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$? Is this necessarily true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. If $x$ belongs to LHS then $x \in A_t$ for some $t \geq 0$. Choose an integer $n >t$. Then  $x \in A_t \subset A_n$ so $x$ belongs to RHS. Obviously RHS is contained in LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in \bigcup\limits_{t \geq 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t$, then there is $t_0 \ge 0$ such that $a \in A_{t_0}$.

Now let $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $t_0 \le n.$ Then we have $a \in A_n.$

Hence $\bigcup\limits_{t \geq 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t  \subseteq \bigcup\limits^\infty_{i = 1, i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$.

That $\bigcup\limits_{t \geq 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t  \supseteq \bigcup\limits^\infty_{i = 1, i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ is clear.